# UFW OpenSSH application port change?

Tags: server, ufw, openssh, port-forwarding

When using UFW I see there are "applications" like OpenSSH or Apache, to name a couple.  If I were to change my SSH default port to something other than the 22, would the OpenSSH application rule map to the new port?  Or, do I need to manually add the rule for this new port?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The quickest way to manually add a new rule for a different SSH port would be with the following command:

```
sudo ufw allow <port number>/tcp
```

inserting your particular port into the command.

While you haven't specifically asked, remember that you need to make your port number change in the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Be sure that you also remember to restart the sshd service after making your change(s) to the configuration file with the command: `sudo systemctl restart sshd`.

---

**Working with ufw application profiles**

Optionally, you could choose to either modify the existing ufw OpenSSH application profile directly, or create an entirely new application profile for your new SSH port.

Adapted from the `ufw` man page:

> APPLICATION INTEGRATION
>
> ```
> ufw  supports  application  integration  by  reading  profiles  located  in `/etc/ufw/applications.d`. 
>
>
>    Syntax for the application profiles is a simple .INI format:
>
>     [OpenSSH]
>     title=Secure shell server, an rshd replacement
>     description=OpenSSH is a free implementation of the Secure Shell protocol.
>     ports=22/tcp
>
>
>    After creating or editing an application profile, users can run:
>
>      sudo ufw app update <name>
> ```

See `man ufw` for additional implementation details.

Comment: And change the port forwarding in the router if you have one.